# Is it possible to start performance profiler from middle of execution of an application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, profiling, performance-testing

I have this computational function that is called from UI. The problem is when I measure its elapsed time using the `Stopwatch`, I see a large decrease in elapsed time after fist call of function. I suspect that a part of function is bypassed in next calls, which is not expected. This is a rather complicated piece of code with many subroutines where thousands of object will be created and tons of calculations are performed.

What comes to mind is to compare the first and second calls using the performance profiler. But when I try to start the profiler after running the application it runs a new instance of the application.

So, what can I do to compare different calls of a function?

Comment: I haven't actually tries this myself, but they seem to be discussing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019) how you can profile between break-points (only).

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible to [attach Visual Studio performance tools to running processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/how-to-attach-and-detach-performance-tools-to-running-processes?view=vs-2017):

> ### To attach to a running process
>
> 1. On the Debug menu, point to Profiler, then Performance Explorer, and then click Attach.
> 2. The Attach Profiler to Process dialog box appears.
> 3. Click the name of the process that you want to attach to.
> 4. Click Attach.

Not sure about your particular scenario, but it seems possible to just record the two separate calls in one profiling session, then select the two peaks consecutively and investigate the difference in the method time distributions in each of them.